# Single sequel query with joins to combine multiple rows from other tables that have the same ID

Tags: mysql, sql, json, join, mysql-5.7

I'm trying to use a single query to get information from 4 different tables and combine them, as some tables may have multiple rows where the ID matches it's relational ID.

I have 4 tables:

- parents
- children - references parent ID
- prices - references child ID
- attributes - references parent ID

Parents Table

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Product Name |

Children Table

| child_id | parent_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 |

Prices Table

| child_id | price |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1.99 |
| 1 | 6.99 |
| 2 | 1.49 |

Attributes Table

| child_id | label | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Colour | Red |
| 1 | Colour | Blue |
| 1 | Size | Large |

Here's the first part, *half* what I want. But how do I append the prices and attributes to the children?

```
const query = 'SELECT parents.id, parents.title, JSON_ARRAYAGG(children.append) AS children \
      FROM parents \
      LEFT JOIN children ON (parents.id = children.parent_id) \
      GROUP BY parents.id';
```

I want to end up with some object like:

```
    [
  {
    "parent_id": 1,
    "title": "Product Name",
    "attributes": [
      {
        "label": "Colour",
        "value": "Red"
      },
      {
        "label": "Colour",
        "value": "Blue"
      },
      {
        "label": "Size",
        "value": "Large"
      }
    ],
    "children": [
      {
        "child_id": 1,
        "prices": [
          {
            "price": 1.99
          },
          {
            "price": 6.99
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "child_id": 2,
        "prices": [
          {
            "price": 1.49
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: What happens if there were attributes for child 2, how does the output change?

Comment: There wouldn’t be attributes for a child product, as they’re relative to the parent table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to generate your sub-json first using [`JSON_OBJECT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-creation-functions.html#function_json-object) + [`JSON_ARRAY_AGG`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html#function_json-arrayagg), for your attributes, your prices, your children. Once you have all of them, you can apply the higher-level aggregation.

```
WITH json_attr AS (
    SELECT child_id, 
           JSON_ARRAYAGG(JSON_OBJECT('label', label, 
                                     'value', value_)) AS json_attr
    FROM attributes
    GROUP BY child_id
), json_pric AS (
    SELECT child_id, 
           JSON_ARRAYAGG(JSON_OBJECT('price', ROUND(price,2))) AS json_pric
    FROM prices
    GROUP BY child_id
), json_child AS (
    SELECT JSON_ARRAYAGG(JSON_OBJECT('child_id', child_id ,
                                     'prices'  , json_pric)) AS json_child
    FROM json_pric
)
SELECT JSON_ARRAYAGG(JSON_OBJECT('parent_id' ,          p.id,
                                 'title'     ,        p.name,
                                 'attributes',  aj.json_attr,
                                 'children'    , cj.json_child )) AS your_json
FROM       parents     p
INNER JOIN children    c ON p.id = c.parent_id
INNER JOIN json_attr  aj ON c.child_id = aj.child_id
CROSS JOIN json_child cj
GROUP BY p.id
```

Check the demo [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/hmcjHvE8yayhxV3c5QQShY/2).

---

In MySQL 5.7, you need to nest subqueries in place of common table expressions:

```
SELECT JSON_ARRAYAGG(JSON_OBJECT('parent_id' ,          p.id,
                                 'title'     ,        p.name,
                                 'attributes',  aj.json_attr,
                                 'children'    , cj.json_child )) AS your_json
FROM       parents     p
INNER JOIN children    c ON p.id = c.parent_id
INNER JOIN (SELECT child_id, 
                   JSON_ARRAYAGG(JSON_OBJECT('label', label, 
                                             'value', value_)) AS json_attr
            FROM attributes
            GROUP BY child_id)  aj ON c.child_id = aj.child_id
CROSS JOIN (SELECT JSON_ARRAYAGG(JSON_OBJECT('child_id', child_id ,
                                             'prices'  , json_pric)) AS json_child
            FROM (SELECT child_id, 
                         JSON_ARRAYAGG(JSON_OBJECT('price', ROUND(price,2))) AS json_pric
                  FROM prices
                  GROUP BY child_id) json_pric) cj
GROUP BY p.id
```

Check the demo [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/hmcjHvE8yayhxV3c5QQShY/3).

Comment: It works fine on your DB Fiddle, but when putting it to the test. I get [this error](https://imgur.com/a/t2PTXNJ).

Comment: what does `select version();` return?

Comment: 5.7, and yours is using 8 - I'm guessing it's an issue with versioning. Unfortunately, I don't have the option to upgrade my MySQL version. I'll take a look at the docs and see the compatibility issues with the functions used in the query above.

Comment: Seems to be timing out, even when setting the limit between 1 and 10.

Comment: In case you have lots of data, consider that this is an expensive query, although required to accomplish what you need to do. If you have little data, then you may be having another unrelated issue, given that this code works in the fiddle within a clean MySQL 5.7 environment.